# Unable to host codeigniter project in a web server

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have created a web project in codeigniter. In my localhost (windows 7) I could run the project with no errors. But when I try to host my project in my university subdomain (the administrator gave me a subdomain to host my files myproject.university.edu.bt). I uploaded all my files via filezilla. When I try to access my page, which starts with a login page. It displays the login button without any of the styles that I have coded for the site. When clicking the login button instead of displaying the next page it gives me an error `The requested URL /sasec/login/user_login was not found on this server. Can any`body tell me what I should do to view/display my pages correctly! Here is my .htaccess file. The university server is running on linux

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# If your website begins from a folder e.g localhost/my_project then 
# you have to change it to: RewriteBase /my_project/
# If your site begins from the root e.g. example.local/ then
# let it as it is
RewriteBase /

# Protect application and system files from being viewed when the index.php is missing
RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)

# Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

# Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public|assets|css|js|images)

# No rewriting
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]

# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: in your localhost its working fine??

Comment: whats error giving after upload to server??

Comment: Yes Abdulla, everything is fine in my localhost

Comment: what is the error after upload??

Comment: 404 Not Found

The requested URL /sasec/login/user_login was not found on this server. This is the message that I get on the browser

Comment: are you using CodeIgnitor 3.0.0??

Comment: can you give me site url??

Comment: I am using codeigniter 2.x ... site url is   sasec.sherubtse.edu.bt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76123/discussion-between-abdulla-and-karma).

Comment: when you find your answer, can you please mark the correct answer, so other people can take the benifit of the nearest solution.

Comment: Amit, I did not get the correct answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `config/routs.php`

**Change this**

```
$route['default_controller'] = '';//give your default controller name
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

*in addition*

Path - `config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to probably change something with

```
RewriteBase /
```

in your htaccess file, link given below will give you more idea.

https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/435526/codeigniter-remove-index-php-while-working-on-virtual-host-on-xampp

Thanks
Amit

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Amit. Ill have a look at your link

Comment: Ok fine, Actually as far as i know when every you host codeigniter instance anywhere, you just need to change in database.php file only, no other file would get effected until and unless you have not added any custom configuration.

Comment: I have configured my database correctly. No issues are there related to database.